# Compare value and return excel

Tags: excel

i'm looking for a formula that automatically call out the value in the table below, when the comparison is matched
Thanks for any help.
[image: Excel picture]

Comment: Welcome to So. What have you tried until now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this standard formula in C8 and fill down.

[image: =INDEX(A$1:D$1, IFERROR(MATCH(B8, A$2:D$2, 0), MATCH(B8, A$3:D$3, 0)))]

Comment: Thanks you so much......but what if i have data at A4(1.3) B4(2.3)........the formula doesn't work

Comment: a) that wasn't the question you asked and b) if you cannot adapt the formula to suit then you need more remedial care than I can offer.